# Determine torque required to operate manual adjustable height desk

Tags: torque

I have a manually operated adjustable height desk (1) that I'd like to motorize, hook up to a raspberry pi etc.

How can I determine the torque required to rotate the mechanism so that I can buy a powerful enough motor?

1: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00626AFXI/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00626AFXI)

Comment: Do you actually have the desk to test on, or is this theoretical?

Comment: You can't beat a cheap electric screwdriver for Torque/$, and it'll probably be enough for a desk if the threads are lubricated, depending on how much weight is on the desk..

Comment: You really need Linux to lift a desk? Is this going to be yet another thing "powered" by a Raspberry Pi? (I'm still waiting to see one power itself).

Comment: Electric "battery" drills usually have reasonably capable motors. Old dead one are often not dead - supply external V and go. The ones that I have dismembered have dual epicyclic gearboxes in series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the table already has a crank, it's pretty easy: just use a spring scale to measure the force on the crank as you pull it through a complete cycle. Be careful to keep the axis of the scale at right angles to the crank arm at all times, and record the highest value you see. The torque is the value on the scale, multiplied by the length of the arm.

Comment: The value in g or N? The length of the arm in what unit?

Comment: Whatever units you like. It's easy enough to convert among oz.-in., lb.-ft., N-m or whatever.